# Parsing data from JSON with python

Tags: python, json, api, parsing, bing

I'm just starting out with Python and here is what I'm trying to do. I want to access Bing's API to get the picture of the day's url. I can import the json file fine but then I can't parse the data to extract the picture's url.

Here is my python script:

```
import urllib, json

url = "http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?    format=js&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

print data

print data["images"][3]["url"]
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Robin/PycharmProjects/predictit/api.py", line 9, in <module>
    print data["images"][3]["url"]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

FYI, here is what the JSON file looks like:
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US

Comment: There is only one element under `'images'`, why did you pick `data["images"][3]`?

Comment: From an example you gave you should use 0 index

Answer (score 0):

```
print data["images"][0]["url"]
```

there is only one object in "images" array

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only one element in the `images` list, you should have `data['images'][0]['url']`.

You can also see that under the "Viewer" tab in the "json viewer" that you linked to.